# QWebEngineView opening local HTML

Tags: html, qt, qtwebengine

I want to open an local `HTML` in case you have no internet connection and `Loadfinished(bool)` property is false.
I have my `HTML` file in resource file called `icons.grc` in which the path is `/html/error.html`

When I use the `load(QUrl())` function to load the `HTML`, only blank page is visible. Although the `loadfinished()` property is true which means it was loaded without any problem.

my code on loading the local url

```
view->load(QUrl("/html/error.html"));
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `.qrc` files need to [specify](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#using-resources-in-the-application) file location, so you can do it like this:

```
view->load(QUrl("qrc:/html/error.html"));
```

Or you can use  [`QWebEngineView::setHtml()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#setHtml) for static content of html pages.

Works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks silly me, totally forgot about that qrc because when iwas taking a icon from the resource file i didnt have a problem. Weird.